# 100% width Twitter Bootstrap 3 template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a bootstrap newbie and I have a 100% wide template that I want to code with bootstrap. The first column begins at the left corner and I have a Google map the stretches to the rightmost. I thought I could do this with `container-fluid` class, but that doesn't seem to be available any longer. I have no idea how to achieve that layout with bootstrap 3. I am using the Geometry PSD template from themeforest, the link here if you want to see the layout : http://themeforest.net/item/geometry-design-for-geolocation-social-networkr/4752268

Comment: You can customize Bootstrap to use `@container-*` widths as 100%. Also, `.container-fluid` is coming back in 3.1.0. :)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, you would need to use a custom wrapper and set its width to 100%.

```
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/72278) is a working example on Bootply

If you prefer not to add a custom class, you can acheive a very wide layout (not 100%) by wrapping everything inside a `col-lg-12` ([wide layout demo](http://www.bootply.com/94398))

**Update for Bootstrap 3.1**

The `container-fluid` class has returned in Bootstrap 3.1, so this can be used to create a full width layout (no additional CSS required)..

[Bootstrap 3.1 demo](http://bootply.com/116382)

Comment: You need to be careful. The row has a -15px margin left and right. That is compensated by the container which has a 15px padding. Best way is to add that padding to your container-full and then use rows and cols to make your grid.

Comment: @rootman I'm using class="container container-full" and that seems to be working.

Comment: Use container-fluid together with a col-md-12 to get a full size row. There will be a gutter (standard 15px on each side) which needs to be removed. Easiest way is to remove it manually, by using the following custom css:     #SomeId div { padding-left:0; padding-right:0; }

Comment: Thanks for the tip... container-fluid worked well for me, no other changes required. The gutter did not present a problem because setting the background-color of the contained class rendered the color to the edges, as desired, while the text and other elements were nicely offset slightly, also as desired.

Answer (score 30):

This is the complete basic structure for **100% width layout** in **Bootstrap v3.0.0**. You shouldn't wrap your `<div class="row">` with `container` class. Cause `container` class will take lots of margin and this will not provide you full screen (100% width) layout where bootstrap has removed **container-fluid** class from their mobile-first version v3.0.0.

So just start writing `<div class="row">` without container class and you are ready to go with 100% width layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Basic 100% width Structure</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
    .red{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 red">Test content</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 green">Another Content</div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To see the result by yourself I have created a bootply. See the live output there. http://bootply.com/82136 And the complete basic bootstrap 3 100% width layout I have created a gist. you can use that. Get the gist from [here](https://gist.github.com/shahariaazam/6636007)

Reply me if you need more further assistance. Thanks.

Comment: thank you. It never came to my mind! this one works better than the previous solution.

Comment: This solution adds a horizontal scrollbar in FF because of the margin on .row. The bootstrap docs say that .row should always be used inside a container because of this - 
Folks looking to create fully fluid layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport) must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0 15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows. - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: Nealio is correct. You should still use a container. I wrap my full-width rows in a .container-full with this CSS declaration: `.container-full { padding: 0 15px; }`

Comment: I tried the padding: 0 15px; as suggested here and on the getbootstrap.com docs, but also still have the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in bootstrap. I solved it by adding the following to the container element where your full screen rows are placed: padding: 0 15px;
 margin-left: 0px; 
 margin-right: 0px;

Comment: Don't all `.row`s need to be contained within a `.container`?

Comment: Erik Flowers wrote a great [article](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) on the container/row relationship, I recommend reading it!

Answer (score 27):

Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) 3.3.5 and `.container-fluid`, this is how I get full width with no gutters or horizontal scrolling on mobile. Note that `.container-fluid` was re-introduced in 3.1.

**Full width on mobile/tablet, 1/4 screen on desktop**

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Adds 15px left/right padding --> 
  <div class="row"> <!-- Adds -15px left/right margins -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="padding-left: 0, padding-right: 0"> <!-- col classes adds 15px padding, so remove the same amount -->
      <!-- Full-width for mobile -->
      <!-- 1/4 screen width for desktop -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full width on all resolutions (mobile, table, desktop)**

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Adds 15px left/right padding -->
  <div class="row"> <!-- Adds -15px left/right margins -->
    <div>
      <!-- Full-width content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

You're right using `div.container-fluid` and you also need a `div.row` child. Then, the content must be placed inside without any grid columns.
If you have a look at the docs you can find this text:

> - Rows **must** be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Not using grid columns it's ok as stated here:

> - Content **should** be placed within columns, and only columns **may** be immediate children of rows.

And looking at [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) example, you can read this text:

> **Full width, single column**: No grid classes are necessary for full-width elements.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/gerardnll/pen/wIqvn) a live example showing some elements using the correct layout. This way you don't need any custom CSS or hack.

Answer (score 5):

In BOOTSTRAP 4 you can use

```
<div class="row m-0">
my fullwidth div
</div>
```

... if you just use a .row without the .m-0 as a top level div, you will have unwanted margin, which makes the page wider than the browser window and cause a horizontal scrollbar.