# Twitter Bootstrap: how to avoid scrollbars with combination of .container-fluid and .row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, row

I am working on my first responsive webseite using twitter bootstrap. After some learning curve, it now works ok, but there is still something which really annoys me.
Test webseite is here:
[www.malle-land.de/fileadmin/Onepage/index.html](http://www.malle-land.de/fileadmin/Onepage/index.html)

If I am using  the combination  everything is ok, except margins (left and right) are rather tall.
Therefore I have now started to use , but then I always get a horizontal scroll bar and especially on smaller devices, like my iPad, it seems as if you could move things around, which you cannot.

From looking at the css, it seems to be related to the -15px margin of row, but eliminating this does not help.

How can I avoid this horizontal scrollbar?

Thanx.

Bernhard

Comment: You can put `overflow-x:hidden` on `body`

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% width Twitter Bootstrap 3 template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449918/100-width-twitter-bootstrap-3-template)

Comment: See the duplicate, the @Skelly answer is a good thing...

Comment: Ok, it seems I found some solution. Thanks for your hints. In order to make it work, I have made the following changes:
- removed the .row margin-right: -15px in bootstrap.css
- changed padding-right: 40px of the social-nav into margin-right: 40px in one of my style.css files.

Now it seems to work!
:-)